# SPARK AR storing values

Tags: spark-ar-studio

Guys I am creating a game where users collect various items in. I want to display the items collected on the side of my screen in the sequence it was collected. I can't figure out any way to create this in the patch editor. Is there anyone who can give me some pointers ?

something like this
[image: Text]

Comment: Could you add some code, please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you will be able to do it through the patch editor, but did you try using scripts? Maybe using some variables to store values or an array. As I don't know how the users collect the items I'm supposing that you could make a logic that every time the item is collected by the user it is sent to an array, and you can use that array to show the content of that array as images at the left bar. What do you think about it? Make sense to you?

In case you would like to give Scripts a try, here's the documentation address: https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/scripting/scripting-basics

Comment: Thanks ! i solved it using script. Being a traditional programmer, using the scripts is so so much easier than using the patch thingy